# How to properly call confirmTransaction so that it is not deprecated?

Tags: web3.js, confirmtransaction

In keeping with the official examples:

```
const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    keypair.publicKey,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
);
await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
```

We get this notice: `@deprecated - Instead, call confirmTransaction using a TransactionConfirmationConfig`

I googled around and reviewed the specs and the code and have not been able to resolve the new correct way to use confirmTransaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
  keypair.publicKey,
  web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
)

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

await connection.confirmTransaction({
  blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
  signature: airdropSignature,
})
```